# Layout problems on different ios devices

Tags: ios, fonts

I'm using a storyboard with some compoments like labels and buttons. The problem is that the captions are too big for my mobile display so the last words will be cutted.
I noticed that the font size seems a little bit bigger than in other apps so I want to ask what the default font size is?
And if I reduce the font, however, there may be problems on various devices, e.g. the presentation on an iPhone or an iPad?
Is it necessary to create different storyboards, each one for every device or what is the usual procedure?

Comment: There is an option called "minimum font scale" which may be useful, and there is this built-in functionality to adapt your UI to different devices: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheAdaptiveModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH19-SW1  & https://www.raywenderlich.com/162311/adaptive-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called "minimum font scale" which may be useful, and there is this built-in functionality to adapt your UI to different devices:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheAdaptiveModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH19-SW1

And a tutorial from a site that has helped me wrap my head around a lot of iOS concepts (this is the one I used, got updated for ios11)

https://www.raywenderlich.com/162311/adaptive-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started

Comment: I think that the layout management in ios is a bit mind blowing. But your tips and links will help me. Because it would be unfair to accept only one answer, I say thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution With Xcode 9:**

 Xcode story board has an options to separate configuration for User Interface Elements for different size (iPad & iPhone) and different orientation (Landscape and Portrait), which are Any, Compact, Regular integrated with [Size Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html).

Size class also allows to set different font size for iPhone & iPad.

Follow these steps, for easy under standing, how to use Size class to solve your problem.

1. Add label in your story board - view controller layout
2. Select label and open 'Attribute Inspector'
3. There is a small '+' icon on left side of 'Font' attribute. Click on '+' icon. It will give you a small popover with size options for your label font.
4. For iPhone it will show you compact width and regular height by default set/selected. Now change/set height and width both as Regular and Click on 'Add Variation', which will add a new variation for font size for iPad (a device with regular height and width).
5. Change font size from 17 to 40 for variation with 'wR x hR' (As shown in this snapshot)

[image]

**Here is result of variation in iPhone and iPad**

[image]